# Test that an element is in a list with junit 4.12

Tags: java, java-8, junit4

I have the next test:

```
public void test() {
  final File dir = new File("/workspaces/").getAbsoluteFile();
  List<File> testList = object
      .getList(dir, “string1, string2);
  assertNotNull(testList);
  int resultSize = testList.stream().filter(
      target -> target.getPath().equals(“s”tring1) ||
          target.getPath().contains("String2withTransformation"))
      .collect(Collectors.toList()).size();

  assertEquals(2, resultSize);
}
```

The idea of the test it's to filter if after call the getList method I will have with the string params, I will have these strings in the testList, the first one with the same value and the second one with the String2withTransformation plus some path for that reason I'm using contains, but this test seems problematic or not accurate, any ideas of how can I improve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please take more time to improve your question. I have trouble understanding the sentences, and the code is not valid (there's missing/misplaced double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following you and I certainty can't follow your code (sorry, but what list are you even testing?), but based on the description don't you want something like:

```
  List<some-type> myList = ...... ;
  
  Assert.assertTrue(myList.contains(some-value));
```